# Laravel 4 : How to get data from a table in a many-to-many relationship with orderBy?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, many-to-many

I have two tables related with a many-to-many relationship by a **pivot** table, conversations_user. I have this working fine in my controller :

**Controller**

```
public function create()
    {
        $loginuser = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
        $user_id = $loginuser->id;
        $conversations = $loginuser->conversations;
        return View::make('brightcms.Conversations.Conversations',array('user_id'=>$user_id,'conversations'=>$conversations));
    }
```

Now I want to get the conversations arranged in descending order according to a `created_at` column in the conversations table + reverse() . **I tried :**

```
$conversations = $loginuser->conversations->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get()->reverse();
```

but it returns an error message. Thank you!

---

Comment: What errors you got ?

Comment: $conversations = $loginuser->conversations->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get(); It's ok? If you just want to descending order for conversation table. What is your `reverse()` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like you can lazy eager load in the conversations in the order you wish

```
public function create()
{
    $loginuser = Auth::user();
    $loginuser->load(['conversations' => function($q)
    { 
        $q->orderBy('created_at', 'desc'); 
    }]);
    View::make('....', ['user' => $loginuser]);
}

$user->conversations; // your ordered conversations collection
```

If you already have the collection you can `sortBy` or `sortByDesc`. Though as mentioned you have access to `reverse` on a collection if it is in order but you just want it reversed.

[Eager Loading w/ Constraints](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading)

[Collection Methods](http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html)